# auto-indent python string and write in an HTML file

Tags: python, html, format

I have a string in python that I have to write to an HTML file. Is there any routine in Python that takes in a string such as

`"( Root ( AB ( ABC ) ( CBA ) ) ( CD ( CDE ) ( FGH ) ) )"`.

and writes it in an indented form to an HTML file?

```
(Root 
    (AB
        (ABC)
        (CBA)
    )
    (CD 
        (CDE)
        (FGH)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works just roughly put together

```
def format(text):
  depth = 0
  result = ''
  text = text.replace(' ', '')
  for i in range(len(text)):
    c = text[i]
    if c == '(': 
      depth += 1
      result += '\n' + '  ' * depth + '('
    elif c == ')': 
      depth -= 1
      if text[i-1] != ')':
        result += ')'
      else:
        result += '\n' + '  ' * depth + ')'
    else:
      result += c
  return result.strip()

s = "( Root ( AB ( ABC ) ( CBA ) ) ( CD ( CDE ) ( FGH ) ) )"
print(format(s))
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IS2q/5.js"></script>
```

You should understand why people aren't so enthusiastic to answer this question. You are entering into the department of parsing but ignoring the complexities of it. To achieve your goal ***correctly*** you would need a defined grammar of the original format then you would need to parse based on that grammar. The resulting internal structure, i.e. the parse tree/syntax tree, would then need be formatted into the desired form.

My suggestion would be to use a well established standard such as json to represent your data instead of a custom one, i.e. the original text.